# Pass value via hidden_field in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a rating system in my app, i tried Rateit but couldnt get it to work so thought I would try and build my own, plus this way I am hoping to learn a lot more by understanding the process

At the moment I am trying to pass the value of the clicked star

#### Form

```
<%= form_for @rating do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :ratings, :id => "hiddenRating", :value => '' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :recipe_id, :value => @recipe.id %>
  <div class="ratings">
    <ul>
      <li id="firstStar"></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#firstStar').click(function(){
    $('#hiddenRating').value = 1;
  });
});
```

So the idea is that if a user clicks the first star then a value of 1 should be passed as the ratings value within the form, this does not happen as I do not know what to pass within

```
:value => ''
```

Im sure there are much better ways to do this but as i said I want to learn piece by piece so that by the end I can put it all together, of course if someone has a better suggestion then please let me know.

### Edit

#### Controller

```
def new
  @rating = Rating.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @rating }
  end
end

def create
  @rating = Rating.new(params[:rating])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @rating.save
      format.html { redirect_to @rating, notice: 'Rating was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @rating, status: :created, location: @rating }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @rating.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ok so i just tried this $('#hiddenRating').attr('value', 1); and it works, it posted the value 1

Comment: I'm not sure what your controller looks like, but don't forget to verify the user id there. Don't rely on the user_id in your form being valid data. It can be faked.

Comment: I have updated question with my controller, how could the current_user.id be faked?

Comment: Definitely read a few guides on this: [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) and [Healthy Skepticism](http://librairie.immateriel.fr/fr/read_book/9780596527440/ch08)

Comment: so good practice would be to verify that the current_user.id matches that of the current_user.id who is in session

Comment: Yes. Any input from a user can be faked or used to transmit malicious code. Rails provides a lot of transparent help with this (i.e. escaping SQL), but you should also make sure you verify input.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so hopefully this may help someone else in a similar situatio, my form now looks like this

```
<%= f.hidden_field :ratings, :id => "hiddenRating"%>#Value has been removed
```

And my Jquery looks like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#firstStar').click(function(){
  $('#hiddenRating').val(1);
 });
});
```

There was no need to pass the value within the form as .val() assigns it to the id

That's my understanding anyway